# Unable to create Kali Linux bootable USB with Windows10/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, kali-linux, bootable

I am trying to Triple boot Kali Linux with windows and Ubuntu. Ubuntu and Windows 10 are both already installed on my Dell-Inspiron. I was following the tutorial at [Making a Kali Bootable USB Drive](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/kali-linux-live-usb-install/) to make the Bootable Kali USB Drive. I was able to create it on both Windows and Ubuntu, but when I go to the boot menu and try to boot from the USB, nothing happens and I get the usual page where I have to select which OS to boot into. Can someone point me into the right direction?

I ran the command

```
sudo kvm -cdrom "/home/vipin/Downloads/kali-linux-light-2016.1-amd64.iso" \
-hda "/dev/sdb" -m 1024 -boot d
```

`/dev/sdb` corresponds to my pen drive of 16 GB as shown in the image below
This image shows the correct configuration of my drives: http://postimg.org/image/ijpto5kkv/.
`/dev/sda` is the primary drive of 500 GB size

When I was trying to install the kali via this command you specified above, this screen appeared: http://postimg.org/image/mtza5zx11/

Here I am not sure what the `/dev/sda` corresponds to? Size of the `/dev/sda` is actually 500 GB and not the size of the pen drive on which I am trying to install the kali linux is 16 GB. Is the setup trying to create another partition on my pen drive by the name `/dev/sda`?
http://postimg.org/image/d2obrfgq7/

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 457.9G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1  14.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  14.5G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  `
```

Comment: You have kali and ubuntu already installed and want to install widnows algonside? Why do you have Kali on a bootable USB?

Comment: i have ubuntu and win10 already, i want to install kali

Comment: second sentence in your question says the opposite. Edit it.

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB? Give the exact environment and commands/process you used, that linked page has multiple ways listed.

Comment: I tried all the processes mentioned here for windows/linux - http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install

Comment: Perhaps the USB isn't formatted properly. you could try [LinuxLive](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/), I've used it multiple times before and it's straightforward. Are you sure you're trying to boot from the USB? Could you include a picture of your boot menu?

Comment: I thought so, formatted several times. But still couldn't get through. Tried taking picture, couldn't. Menu is something like this, first-ubuntu, second- advanced options for ubuntu, third- wondows boot manager, fourth-boot setup menu

Comment: What you described sounds like Grub menu to me. In Dell machines, Boot menu is accessed by pressing down F12 key repeatedly during first few seconds after you power on. From there you should see option to boot into USB listed alongside HDD and CD devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since kali 1.6 until kali 2.0 (sana) , i am pretty sure that kali on usb gives errors in most of cases !
except if you created your live usb using DD on a linux box.

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/kali.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

i can't tell you that if you're installing last kali distro (2016) i haven't tried it yet!

but as suggestion here's another way to install it while running ubuntu :

simply install KVM and use the folowing command :

```
kvm -cdrom "/path/to/kali.iso" -hda "/dev/sdXY" -m 1024 -boot d
```

/dev/sdXY is the partition where you want to install kali-linux e.g /dev/sda3

Note : while you already have another linux installed (ubuntu) , you can skip/ignore grub_installation step , at the end just update-grub on ubuntu!
i hope this will help :)

### updates

you don't have problems with previous commands ! but you're confuse how to chose your **16gb pendirve** and how you deal with **partitionning step** !

in a terminal run: `lsblk`

[image]

as you see in the screenshot you can identify your 16GB.

for example if i was going to install on my 4GB(3.7G) i'll chose **/dev/sda**    , if my pendrive was the one which have SIZE=465.8G i'll chose **/dev/sdc** and so on .
**Q** : why /dev/sd**X** and not /dev/sd**XY**?
**A** : because your are going to install on a pendrive and you are going to use whole of it , if you were going to install on a partition inside your hard drive that time you'll use /dev/sd**XY** ,( and also you'll have chance to *ignore/skip* *grub-install* step if you already have another linux with bootloader on your machine )!

i started installing *kali-linux-light-2016.1-amd64* on my 4g(3.7g) pendrive to get screenshots !

and my command according to my pendrive(3.7G) and my iso is :
`kvm -cdrom "/.img/kali-linux-light-2016.1-amd64.iso" -hda "/dev/sda" -m 1024 -boot d`

*sure you don't have problems with first steps , you can go directly to step 9*

1)
[image]
2)
[image]
3)
[image]
4)
[image]
5)
[image]
6)          any hostnam you like i recommand to make it unic in case you wanted to change it later using scripts you won't mess up other files inside **/etc**.

[image]
7)
[image]
8 )
[image]
9 )         manual to know what you're doing .
[image]
10)          select your 16G .
[image]
11)        here make sure of (**use as** ext4, **format** yes, **mountpoint** / , bootflag on)
[image]
12)
[image]
13)
[image]
 as you saw i ignored swap because you can creat a virtual image file for swape insteed of eatting pendrive space .
14)
[image]
15)
[image]
if you chose yes it will tell you enter **HTTP PROXY infos** of course you don't know what to put there , simply leave it blank , but at the end you'll have to add kali repos manually in */etc/apt/sources.list*
http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories

16)
[image]
17)
[image]

18)
[image]

it will take a moment in removing live pakage

after installation ends boot into your new installed kali from there using kvm :

```
kvm -hda "/dev/sdX" -m 1024
```

[image]
[image]

in case you wanna creat swape here's the way :
after you boot into new installed kali inside pendrive
*sawp: 1) creat empty raw image:*
    sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/.swap.img bs=1M count=512
this will give 512 mb (control size trough count=XX)
*swap: 2) add it to fstab:*
use nano or any text editor open `/etc/fstab`
add the following line to it

```
/.swap.img       none       swap     sw      0    0
```

related to step **15** :
from new installed kali delete anything inside /etc/apt/sources.list and  add following 2 lines to:
    deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

while you still in your new installed kali please install ralink in order to use wifi with the following command :

```
apt-get update ; apt-get install firmware-misc-nonfree
```

*adding normal user :*

```
adduser newusername              #creat user
addgroup newusername             #cerat group
adduser newusername newusername  #add user to the group
adduser newusername sudo         #add user to sudo group to be able to use sudo.
```

finally i think this should help you as i hope so :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35591/discussion-on-answer-by-younes-unable-to-create-kali-linux-bootable-usb-with-win).

Comment: @terdon can we attach screenshot in comments?

Comment: @vipin8169 you can provide links with this format: `[link text](http://example.com)`. However, if you feel you have to, you should probably add them to your question instead.

Comment: @younes please help!

Comment: check out chat :)

Answer (score 0):

I create my USBs with [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) tool. It works perfectly when I select it as a boot device. Maybe your boot menu is disabled by default, so make sure you enable it in your BIOS Settings (that happened me in a Packard Bell Laptop, for example). Try to find out which key is the one to access the boot menu, as it depends on the brand.

Source: I also have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my hard drive and Kali Linux (Sana).