# An installation step failed! Kali Linux 2016.2 64 Bit

Tags: debian, kali-linux, system-installation, virtualbox, vmware

I'm getting an error
while trying to install Kali Linux 2016.2 64-bit in my VMware machine.

> An installation step failed. 
> You can try to run the failing item again from the menu,
> or skip it and choose something else. 
> The failing step is: Install the system

I downloaded `kali-linux-2016.2-amd64.iso` torrent
from [Kali Linux's official website](https://www.kali.org/downloads).

I created a virtual machine by selecting `Linux > Debian 8.x 64-Bit`.

I gave the virtual machine 30.00 GB hard drive space and 2.00 GB RAM.

1. Booted up the ISO and selected Graphical Install.
2. After completing a few steps, I came up to Partition Disks step.
3. I selected "Guided - use entire disk", then clicked continue.
4. Then I selected the Hard disk and clicked continue.
5. In Partitioning scheme,
   I selected "All files in one partition (recommended for new users)".
6. Then the following message came:

   ```
   The following partitions are going to be formatted:

    partition #1 of SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sda) as ext4
    partition #5 of SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sda) as swap

   write changes to disks?
   yes or no
   ```

   I selected yes and clicked continue, and the installation was going well.
7. But, after a few moments, Kali Linux installation froze
   and showed me the error:

   > *Installation step failed*
   >
   > ---
   >
   > An installation step failed. 
   > You can try to run the failing item again from the menu,
   > or skip it and choose something else. 
   > The failing step is: Install the system

   (See [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfDF6.png).)

If I click continue, then after a while the error reappears. 
I tried a lot of times to install, but failed every time.

My host system:

- Processor: Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M430 @2.27GHz
- RAM: 8.00 GB
- Graphics: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470
- OS: Windows 7 Home Premium, 64-bit 6.1.7601, Service Pack 1

My VMware:

- Version: 12.1.0 build-3272444 (64-bit)

Comment: Why install? Download image:
https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/

Comment: VMware Image version is 2016.1 but current Kali Linux version is 2016.2 
and I also found that people are having similar problem with their physical computer also.

Comment: There is exist one magic command: `apt-get`. It can transform 2016.1 to 2016.2 in one command.

Comment: Yeah! I know it, but why I can't able to install it in VMware that makes me mad, I'm geek so I've to figure out the problem with the help of other! not only me I searched over internet and there's a lot  of people facing same kind of problem while installing Kali Linux either in VM or Physical Machine! I need to figure out this kali linux installation problem because I thought after I install it to VMware then I would install it to my system! But I'm failing install it to VMware. Thanks

Comment: Kali is a rolling distro which based on debian testing, so it is always in beta phase. Fill a bugreport at kali site, then be patient. It is the normal behavior a beta system. If you have power+time, feel free to fix it then share the patch.
Kali is not a stable distribution, you have to deal with it. Minor and major bugs are totally normal and not your fault.

Comment: Go back into the main installation menu, then export your logs (if network is operational) or get a shell and examine `/var/log/syslog` from there, or switch to another virtual terminal for some debug info (Alt+F[1234] in text mode, not sure about graphical).

Comment: @FerencWágner, Here's the Syslog result of failed kali linux installation. 

see screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/xWSLHdH.png

Comment: Please check the sha1sum of your downloaded `kali-linux-2016.2-amd64.iso` against the one provided on https://www.kali.org/downloads/, that is: `25cc6d53a8bd8886fcb468eb4fbb4cdfac895c65`.

Comment: @FerencWágner can you please tell me step by step procedure about how to check sha1sum ?

Comment: Issue the following command in the directory of your downloaded ISO (one long line): `echo 25cc6d53a8bd8886fcb468eb4fbb4cdfac895c65\ \ kali-linux-2016.2-amd64.iso | sha1sum -c` (assuming you did not rename the file).

Comment: https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/03/12/step-failed-installing-system-error-kali-linux/
here is a link that will help you

Comment: making the capacity 60 G for the hard disk, works smoothly.

Comment: you may find usefull infos here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/260347/134906

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem, and I have fixed it by increasing the space for the hard drive. By default you have 8 GB, increase it to 30 GB or more. And continue with the installation.

Comment: I did that thingi, but didn't solve my problem:(

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution might be specifying file system usage, meaning is that using a single container not a seperated for /usr, /var, /tmp ..

Comment: Installation failed on trying to use separated partitions, but as suggested using single partition succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

I faced exactly the same predicament as your's and extensive search on internet did not yield any straight-forward answer.

My host OS level(Windows 7), VMWare version and Kali linux version & settings for Kali install attempt are similar to yours with the exception 
- that I did chose separate partition for /home, /var & /temp
- I chose varying disk capacity size which you chose as 30G

While trying repeatedly to install with differing settings I noticed following pattern:
- for 8G disk capacity setting the install step failed after approx. 20% completion
- for 20G disk capacity setting the install step failed after approx. 40% completion
- for 40G disk capacity setting the install step failed after approx. 80% completion

Finally the install step succeeded with 60G disk capacity value. So try increasing your disk capacity and give it a shot!

Comment: I tried with 60GB still it's a failure...

Comment: Are you kidding me? 60 GB for a Kali installation? I'm giving it 8 and its a lot!

Comment: This actually helped me. But I kept it above 30 GB and below 60 GB. 58GB to be exact.

Comment: Mine failed at 20GB and worked at 30GB.